# Automation of tests and storing the results in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I have written a tester for one of my component models and I want to test it with a large set of boundary conditions. I dont want to manually change the values in the boundaries and note down the end results, since that would take forever. I therefore tried to automate that process by reading an .mat file that contains my set of boundary conditions and storing the last value in time of the variables that I am interested in in another .mat file that I will then post process. In that .mat file, each line represents one model run and each column the last value in time for the particular variables that I want to store. However, I cant overcome the error `Warning: Undeclared variable or command: Model.Variable`. Below my code that I have written in the scripts section of Dymola:

```
openModel("pathToModel");

startTime :=0;
stopTime :=30;

data := readMatrix("BC.mat", "BC_MatrixName", nrows, ncols);

resultsMatrix := zeros(size(data, 1), 2);

for i in 1:size(data, 1) loop

  SubmodelBoundary1.value1 := data[i, 1];
  ... More Bc's

  simulateModel("ModelName", start=startTime, stop=stopTime, method="dassl', tolerance=1e-4);

  resultsMatrix[i, 1] := ModelName.VarName[end];

end for;
```

I tried multiple different ways of accessing the variable. I have also made sure that the variable that I want to read is set to public in the model. When I try to write the variable to the file before I call the `simulateModel()` function, it is possible as well. Please note that I didnt include the `writeMatrix()` command needed at the end, since that works for me.

If someone could help me with how I can access variables after the simulating the model that would be awesome. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Dymola supports running multiple simulations of one model with different parameters.

If it were only one parameter you could use sweep parameter available in the GUI. Multiple parameters is also supported, but simulates all possibly combinations of parameters (or a Monte-Carlo subset), which isn't what you want.

However, there is a low level scripting command that can be configured to run the specific cases:

```
simulateMultiExtendedModel("ModelName", 
  start=startTime, 
  stop=stopTime, 
  method="dassl", 
  tolerance=1e-4, 
  initialNames={"SubmodelBoundary1.value1", ...}, 
  initialValues=data, 
  finalNames={"VarName", ...});
```

Alternatively: Use `DymolaCommands.SimulatorAPI.simulateMultiExtendedModel` that also contain some documentation for this functionality.

Note that this command will run simulations in parallel.

Comment: Hey Hans, thanks for your answer! I will try to get on with your method, however, your function call (I believe) will produce a Dymola results .mat file for each simulation separately. This is problematic since those files are hard to post process + I would have loads of files to deal with. Do you have an idea how I can access specific variables of the model after running it through a command?

Comment: Because that would allow me to generate a result file that is much easier to post process and only contains final values of specific variables of the model that I want to read

Comment: @trecpy Did you miss the "finalNames" part of the answer?

Comment: Yes I am sorry, it didnt show me the bar to slide over the code view. I will check it out and post an update on how it went. Thanks again!